# How to compare conditions of an agent with all connected agents in statechart

Tags: anylogic, agent, statechart

I am working on my thesis associated with modeling farmers' behaviors in a river basin. I am having 6
agents that contain different populations of farmers. These farmers have been located on the GIS map as the environment (main) in anylogic. I also defined the connection between populations of 6 agents by coding on the main startup and using "Link to Agent". Now, I'd like to define agents'  behaviors through statecharts. But I have some difficulties. I have to compare the income of each farmer to the income of all connected farmers. How can I do that? What I have tried to define condition transition and write (for example if the income of each farmer is less than the income of all connected farmers in its network then do specific action):

IncomeT<ALL_CONNECTED.IncomeT

but it didn't work. Got any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

not quite clear who is your agent for which you are designing your state chart. Is it some entity (say Area) which contains a population of farmers? If  yes, then why would you connect/link one Area to another? If you agent is a famer (which is not how you described it, but seems logical) then you would just store (and update) "minimum population income" in some variable and compare individual income with that stored value.
Alternatively you can use min() function. More on that: https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fdata%2Fcollections-statistics-api.html